# "unknown escape sequence" warning when using sed in C program

Tags: c, linux, sed, escaping

I want to use `sed` command to extract a target string from a source string.

If the command is executing in Linux shell, it works well. Here is the example,

```
echo A=B | sed -e 's/.*=\(.*\)/\1/'
```

This command extracts the string after "=", and its result is a string "B".

However, if this command is invoked from a C program, such as

```
popen("echo A=B | sed -e 's/.*=\(.*\)/\1/'", "r")
```

A warning message `{"warning: unknown escape sequence: '\)'}` is shown while compiling it.

There are several answers that suggests to add a backslash before `'\)'`, but it is not working in this case. Does anyone know how to work this out?

**P.S.** By adding a backslash before all the '\', which leads the code to `popen("echo A=B | sed -e 's/.*=\\(.*\\)/\\1/'", "r")`, it works.
However, the result is "B\n" instead of "B", is there any way to remove the suffix "\n"?

Comment: In C you need to escape special characters, so you have to write `'\\'` if you want to have 1 `'\'`. ==> `fopen("echo A=B | sed -e 's/.\\*=\(.\\*\\)/\\1/'", "r")`

Comment: Add another \ before *every* occurrence of \.

Comment: Do you mean `popen` instead of `fopen`?

Comment: @KeineLust My mistake, it should be popen...

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, the C program works with `popen = ("echo A=B | sed -e 's/.*=\\(.*\\)/\\1/'", "r")`, however, the result is "B\n" instead of "B", is there  a way to solve this?

Comment: @bamb00dark,  The trailing newline can be eliminated by passing the `-n` option to `echo`

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem is that you have to double the escape character `\` to produce a real escape in the string, so you have to write:

```
popen("echo A=B | sed -e 's/.*=\\(.*\\)/\\1/'", "r");
```